# iDB2InvalidConnectionStringException connecting to AS400 on new server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, db2, ibm-midrange

So we've got a setup with an ASP.NET MVC / C# web app running on a Windows Server and connecting to an AS400 (DB2 midrange) database, and everything's working fine.

But then when IT tried to set up a new server and moved the app over, suddenly it's giving a 500 error. To debug it we installed Visual Studio Community on that same server and I copied over the dev (pre-compiled) version of the app to run, and the first time it tried to reach the AS400, I get the following exception:

> Type: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2InvalidConnectionStringException
> Message: "The ConnectionString property is invalid."
>
> Type: System.TypeInitializationException
> Message: "The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Constants' threw an exception.
>
> Type: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2DCFunctionErrorException
> Message: "An unexpected exception occurred.
> Type: System.AccessViolationException, Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt..

I think I remember seeing this same error on a user's PC for a desktop app, too, a while back.

Any idea what the issue is?

All that's needed to obtain the exception is running the following:

```
var connectionString = "DataSource=as400.MYCOMPANY.com; UserID=FAKEUSERNAME; Password=FAKEPASSWORD; InitialCatalog=PRODTEST; DataCompression=True; CheckConnectionOnOpen=True; CharBitDataAsString=True; Naming = System";
var test = new IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection(connectionString);
```

Comment: ? Is it? I'd thought VS Community was free. Either way, I can only assume that IT knows what they're doing from a legal standpoint.

Comment: Problem is, the exact same ConnectionString works fine, both on my local machine and on the currently-used server.

Comment: The AS400/database hasn't changed... as for drivers, I can again only take IT's word that everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Yes. They're the one who came to me with it. We're both stumped and trying from our own ends to figure out what's wrong. He knows nothing of web development and I know nothing of servers.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather a configuration/installation matter.  You have a working environment (the old Windows-server) and a failing environment (the new Windows-server). One approach is to systematically compare the software-component versions on each, especially the Db2-driver being used , and then examine its detailed configuration.  This is troubleshooting, and is best  done by competent experienced __onsite__ people with access to the log files/configs etc.

Comment: At least in JDBC connection strings every property/value pair must be terminated with a semicolon, including the last one. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mustaccio for the answer:

> At least in JDBC connection strings every property/value pair must be terminated with a semicolon, including the last one.

Added a ; to the end of the connection string and it started working. I guess for some reason it allows it to be missing on an older configuration but not a new one.